# php for every div tag get contents between nested tags

Tags: php, regex, rss

I'm very new to PHP and have been trying to find an online example of what I'm searching for in order to generate an XML file (without a database).

Here's the situation and what I'm trying to do:

`includes/articles.php` contains many divs containing links to articles.

Example of an article div:

```
<div class="article random-class-varying-between-divs">
<span class="article-title">
<h4><a href="ARTICLE URI HERE" title="ARTICLE TITLE HERE">ARTICLE TITLE HERE</a></h4>
</span>
</div>
```

Now here is "pseudo-code" of what I'm thinking but don't understand how to do..

Inside of an `rss.php` file:

```
<?php
for every of first 50 <div class="article *">*</div> in includes/articles.php:
<item>
  <title>echo contents_between_h4_<a>_tags</title>
  <link>echo 'http://example.com'uri_from_href_in_h4_<a>_tags</link>
</item>
?>
```

Comment: is articles.php not generated dynamicly? Cant you generate the rss xml from the same datasource, instead of doing it via the html-elements

Comment: Nah, it's just a file for html I write manually by hand. It just uses the .php extension so I can add a few lines of code.

Comment: parse it with DOMDocument - be much easier than a regex

Comment: okay, than the solution is to load it into a DOMDocument() and iterate the nodes

Answer (score 0):

This is not tested but should give you a good headstart to achieving what you want...

```
libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
/* XML will be written to this object */
$xml=new DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace=true;

/* HTML is read from this object */
$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->validateOnParse=false;
$dom->strictErrorChecking=false;
$dom->recover=true;

/* Change the path!! */
$dom->loadHTMLFile( '/path/to/your/page.html' );

libxml_clear_errors();

/* Find all the a tags in html & loop through */
$col=$dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach( $col as $index => $node ){
    /* Add a node to your xml output */
    $item=$xml->createElement('item');
    $xml->appendChild( $item );

    /* Add child nodes to the `$item` */
    $item->appendChild( $xml->createElement('title',$node->nodeValue ) );
    $item->appendChild( $xml->createElement('link', $node->getAttribute('href') ) );
}
/* Save the xml file somewhere */
$xml->save( '/path/to/newxml.xml' );
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to transform an HTML or XML file using [XSLT](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-xslt--net-8657), example:

```
define('MIN_ITEM', 0);
define('MAX_ITEM', 50);

function hasClass($classAttr, $className) {
    return in_array($className, preg_split('~\s+~', $classAttr));
}

$xsl = <<<'EOD'
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl" exclude-result-prefixes="php">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
  <xsl:param name="minItem"/>
  <xsl:param name="maxItem"/>
  <xsl:template match="/html/body">
    <rss version="2.0">
      <channel>
        <xsl:for-each select="//div[php:function('hasClass', string(@class), 'article')][position() &lt; $maxItem][position() &gt; $minItem]">
          <item>
            <title><xsl:value-of select="span/h4/a"/></title>
            <link><xsl:value-of select="span/h4/a/@href"/></link>
          </item>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </channel>
    </rss>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
EOD;

libxml_use_internal_errors(true); // prevent badly formatted html to display warnings

// $htmlFilePath = './includes/articles.php';
$htmldoc = DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile($htmlFilePath); 
$xsldoc = DOMDocument::loadXML($xsl);

$proc = new XSLTProcessor();
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsldoc);
$proc->registerPHPFunctions('hasClass');
$proc->setParameter('', 'minItem', MIN_ITEM - 1);
$proc->setParameter('', 'maxItem', MAX_ITEM + 1);

echo $proc->transformToXML($htmldoc);
```

Note that I used a [custom php function](http://php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.registerphpfunctions.php) `hasClass` to be sure that the class attribute contains the class `article` and not `articleblah` or `articlebluh`. (To do that, the XPath function `contains` doesn't suffice.)

The main interest of using XSLT is that you can use the same stylesheet with few changes for other HTML or XML document. All you need to change is the `match` attribute here: `<xsl:template match="/html/body">` (path to the root element that contains articles) and the `select` attributes.

[An other tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/xmlTutorial/xslttutorial.php)